Max number of endpoints under platform application in AWS SNS
I've created an application where we are creating end-points based upon the device token and publishing message to it.
The questions that i have is whether there is any limit on the number of endpoints w.r.t. device tokens that can be created under a platform application in AWS SNS?
Couldn't find any docs which have number w.r.t to individual device tokens.
